# Postfix (MySQL): Encrypted passwords does not work

Tags: postfix, sasl

**Update:** I've tried to insert the password in plain text in the DB. That works, and I'm now able to send mail as well. I tried setting up the whole thing (using the guide mentioned) again, but with the same result. Any ideas?

**Original question:** Just set up a Postfix / Courier bundle following [this tutorial](http://www.pixelinx.com/2010/10/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-using-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-and-amavis/). I've used this tutorial with luck before, but this time I am having problems sending email. My main problem is that I don't really know where to look for clues on what's causing this error. Mail.log only gives me the following lines,

```
Apr 21 17:38:50 gordon postfix/smtpd[5059]: connect from xxx.xx-xxx-xx.my.isp.carrier[xx.xxx.xx.xxx]
Apr 21 17:38:51 gordon imapd: LOGIN, user=my@domain.com, ip=[::ffff:xx.xxx.xx.xxx], port=[57701], protocol=IMAP
Apr 21 17:38:51 gordon postfix/smtpd[5059]: warning: xxx.xx-xxx-xx.my.isp.carrier[xx.xxx.xx.xxx]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
```

When searching it appears "authentication failure" is a very generic error message and may be caused by a number of different errors - which makes it all the more diffifcult for a newbie like myself to locate the problem.

**System**

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Postfix
- Courier
- SASL with SSL and TLS
- SpamAssassin
- ClamAV
- Amavis

Answer (score 1):

In the [tutorial linked above](http://www.pixelinx.com/2013/09/creating-a-mail-server-on-ubuntu-postfix-courier-ssltls-spamassassin-clamav-amavis/), the author using CRYPT hash algorithm. This fact can be looked in SQL query:

```sql
INSERT INTO `user` (`email`, `password`, `name`) VALUES ("admin@example.com", ENCRYPT("adminpassword"), "Administrator");
```

Saslauthd using pam-mysql to authenticate user, so we need to configure pam-mysql to use same hash algorithm. The configuration file is defined in `/etc/pam.d/smtp`

```
auth    required   pam_mysql.so user=mail passwd=mailpassword host=127.0.0.1 db=mail table=user usercolumn=email passwdcolumn=password crypt=1
account sufficient pam_mysql.so user=mail passwd=mailpassword host=127.0.0.1 db=mail table=user usercolumn=email passwdcolumn=password crypt=1
```

The important parameter is `crypt` because it specifies the method to encrypt the user's password

> - 0 (or "plain") = No encryption. Passwords stored in plaintext. HIGHLY DISCOURAGED.
> - 1 (or "Y") = Use crypt(3) function
> - 2 (or "mysql") = Use MySQL PASSWORD() function. It is possible that the encryption function used by pam-mysql is different from that of the MySQL server, as pam-mysql uses the function defined in MySQL's C-client API instead of using PASSWORD() SQL function in the query.
> - 3 (or "md5") = Use MySQL MD5() function

So, if you need use encrypted password for authentication then set `crypt` parameter so it match with
your original query.

---

Another important parameter is `verbose`. You can set it as 1 so you can know what the pam-mysql was doing.

Further info: [PAM-MySQL Package README readme.php](http://pam-mysql.sourceforge.net/Documentation/package-readme.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am however unable to confirm that it is correct as the setup described in the question is no longer in use.

Comment: Don't worry. Perhaps this answer will be useful  for another future user who has same setup